# Python's __get/set/delattr__, ordinary assignment versus __setattr__, __dict__ vs dir()

Tags: python

I have a few more related OOP Python questions:

- What does these attributes do exactly: `__get/set/delattr__`?
- Why not use just `Myclass.NewAttr = value` instead of `__setattr__`?
- Why does Python use `__dict__`? It keeps the attributes in the end of dir() anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Python Descriptor Methods

> What does these attributes do exactly: `__get/set/delattr__`?

This is a hard one to start with, and fairly advanced - most Python programmers don't need to know this, they just memorize how objects (mostly methods and method decorators) that use this work.

They are special methods that make an object a "descriptor". If that object is looked up through another object, they get invoked. They are how `property`, `classmethod`, and `staticmethod` work. The are also how normal functions can become bound methods.

For example:

```
>>> class Foo:
...     def __init__(self, bar):
...         self.bar = bar
...     @property
...     def baz(self):
...         return bar * 2
>>> Foo.__init__.__get__
<method-wrapper '__get__' of function object at 0x7f1c1d23b158>
```

The `__get__` is invoked when you do `Foo.__init__` (which is invoked by `Foo()`). It binds the instance to the first argument (we usually call it `self`) to the method on the dotted lookup.

```
>>> Foo.baz.__set__
<method-wrapper '__set__' of property object at 0x7f1c1d225e58>
```

That `__set__` method is what is invoked when we try to assign to the `baz` name on the dotted lookup on the left hand side of the assignment (since we didn't define a setter, baz is read-only) and that method raises the following error:

```
>>> f = Foo('bar')
>>> f.baz = 'boink'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

I wrote a canonical and very thorough answer on this subject on StackOverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34554353/541136).

## Assignment versus `__setattr__` (versus `setattr`)

> Why not use just `Myclass.NewAttr = value` instead of `__setattr__`?

Yes, you should do that. `__setattr__` should only be used when implementing special behavior on an object.

There is also a [builtin function called `setattr`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#setattr) - it works if you need to programmatically determine the name you are assigning to, and can't just use a static name in your code.

## `__dict__` versus `dir`

> Why does Python use `__dict__`? It keeps the attributes in the end of `dir()` anyway.

Actually, the attributes (data members) are stored in the dictionary - `dir()` just looks their names up there.

Comment: cool. some artical show example of use the methods __get/set/delattr__ and i still can't figure out when to use them. by the way, i dont understand why you have to use super in those methods....

Comment: Well, descriptors are an advanced topic that most Python programmers don't really need to know about - I haven't had the need to write my own, even. For more on `super` - I have pretty comprehensive answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/576169/understanding-python-super-with-init-methods/27134600#27134600 and here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/222877/how-to-use-super-in-python/33469090#33469090

Comment: i think i get it.. set/get/delattr is methods under "object" (new-style-class), it's very interesting what actually happens when you create new object - when you call the init function - you actually call to the setattr function.. and so.. do you have anything you wrote about what happens behind the scene ? for set get mro multi inhibits (bases,classes) and so?.. i know that most of Python programmers don't need to know this. but i'm really interesting about it. thanks